# How \externaldocument into xr-hyper works?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, external-files, xr

I am using xr-hyper for referencing to an external document on my pc and I elaborated the following code.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{report}


\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb} 


\hypersetup{colorlinks,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black}

\externaldocument[CI-]{Compendio_di_Insiemistica}[C:/Users/Asus/Cloud/Documenti/Universita/Teoria degli Insiemi/Appunti e dispense/Appunti personali/Compendio di Insiemistica/Codice/Compendio_di_Insiemistica.tex]

\begin{document}
    
    Into the following chapter we will assume axm. \eqref{CI-axm: della scelta} holds.
    
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately it does not work so that alternatively I tried to put the external file into the main document using the following command

\externaldocument[CI-]{Compendio_di_Insiemistica.tex`}`

but nothing changed so that I thought to put here a specific question where I ask elucidation about the \externaldocument functioning: I point out I use TeXstudio and I compile with XeLaTeX; consulting the [package documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/xr-hyper.pdf) it seems to me that the correct command was the follow

```
\externaldocument[CI-]{C:/Users/Asus/Cloud/Documenti/Universita/Teoria degli Insiemi/Appunti e dispense/Appunti personali/Compendio di Insiemistica/Codice/Compendio_di_Insiemistica.tex}
```

but it does not work. So could someone help me, please?

Comment: remove the extension `.tex`. xr-hyper reads an `.aux` file (and it will add the extension itself). Notice that the documentation says `{aaa}` and not `{aaa.tex}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay: so do I have to put .aux in place of .tex?

Comment: you need to compile your tex file (often enough so that the references are correct), then the aux is created automatically.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay: now I compile first the external file so that I tried the command below, delecting .tex extension but nothing changed.

\externaldocument[CI-]{Compendio_di_Insiemistica}[C:/Users/Asus/Cloud/Documenti/Universita/Teoria degli Insiemi/Appunti e dispense/Appunti personali/Compendio di Insiemistica/Codice/Compendio_di_Insiemistica]

Where is now the mistake?

Comment: check the log-file if xr-hyper tells you something.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer

To follow three advices:

-No file Compendio_di_Insiemistica.auxLABELS NOT IMPORTED.
***
-Reference `CI-axm: della scelta' on page 1 undefined
***
-There were undefined references.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Now I putted a copy of the external file into the folder of the and thus I compile it: now it seems the code work but in this way there are many auxiliary files into the new folder and this is really annoying. What do you suggest about?

Comment: put them in a subfolder and use `subfolder/file`